# jsr303 validate 2 properties with only one custom validator

Tags: bean-validation

I have a problem with validation. Is it possible to validate two properties of a bean using only one ConstraintValidator? I have something like the following:

```
@Component
public class CheckSomeBeanPropertiesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckSomeBeanProperties, SearchFormBean> {

@Autowired
SomeApplicationService applicationService;

public void initialize(CheckSomeBeanProperties checkSomeBeanProperties) {
}

public boolean isValid(SearchFormBean searchFormBean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

ReturnSearchBean searchBean = applicationService.findBySearchBean(searchFormBean);

if(searchBean.isNoResults()) return false; // it will return the message No data found

if(searchBean.isTooManyDataReturned()) return false; // it will return too many records found

return true;
}
}
```

inside the CheckSomeBeanPropertiesValidator I call the service SomeApplicationService that returns some data searched calling findBySearchBean. Instead to have to call more than one customized ConstraintValidator (and more than one findBySearchBean) is it possible to call only one time the service and check two different properties?

Thanks

bye

Comment: You question is quite vague and you should also post the code on how you use your custom constraint. I am just guessing that you use this custom constraint on two different properties, but you only want to have it once. This is only possible if you use a class level constraint. Then again, I am just guessing :-)

Comment: hi, I use it on class level like: @CheckSomeBeanPropertiesValidator
public class SearchFormBean implements Serializable{ boolean noResults; boolean tooManyDataReturned; ....} but the problem is that I would like to return two different messages depending on which boolean of the bean is true. I do not want to validate 2 different properties calling two times the same service findBySearchBean. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the error message depending on the outcome of the validation you should use *ConstraintValidatorContext*. You can disable the default error message and build your own. Something like:

```
 constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
 constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "{mykey}"  ).addConstraintViolation();
```

You can also adjust the property path of the constraint violation. *ConstraintValidatorContext* offers a fluent API. Just check the Javadocs or explore with your IDE :-)